# GitHub Actions Maven test failing after push?

Tags: java, maven, yaml, github-actions, antlr

I'm not quite sure why this is happening, as it didn't happen on my other project with a nearly identical setup. I'm working on a Java project with Maven and want to run my test suite upon pushing the code to [GitHub](https://github.com/JoshuaCrotts/MiniScheme/tree/yml-testing). I can do a `mvn compile test -Dtest=InterpreterTester` and it will work fine locally. If, however, I push the code to GitHub, the build test fails with a bunch of `cannot find symbol` errors and `package x does not exist.` Again, this doesn't happen locally and I've used a similar setup in a previous project (in fact, the .yml file was copied verbatim and the .pom file only differs in the version of ANTLR). Can anyone see what might be going wrong?

`maven.yml` file:

```
name: tests
on: push
jobs:
  run_tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout the repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 14
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 14
      - name: Cache Maven packages
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ~/.m2
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-m2-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-m2
      - name: Run tests with Maven
        run: mvn compile test -Dtest=InterpreterTester
```

Comment: If the package is just released, you have to wait until the internal maven repository is refreshed.

Comment: @ThiloSchwarz can you explain what you mean?

Comment: What error messages do maven itself show before the actual compilation?

Comment: @TheProgrammer To save traffic, github actions are using a 'local' maven repository, which is managed by  github. This repo has a low refresh rate. That's the reason why the dependencies can be resolved locally but not on github actions.

Comment: It looks like Maven isn’t compiling all of the files when it’s pushed up to the repository… when I do a mvn compile locally, it compiles 45 files. In the remote repo, however, it only compiles 41 which may be the reason it’s throwing unknown symbol errors. Not sure why it’s only getting 41 though.

Comment: @Thilo but that still doesn’t really explain why it hasn’t worked since I started the project… this very same project setup worked for two other larger-scale projects using Maven and ANTLR with automated remote testing…

Comment: @TheProgrammer I checked out your project and got the same error on calling ```mvn clean compile```on commandline. Reason: The compile-plugin don't know anything of your generated resources. I guess your IDE has its own source-paths.

Comment: @Thilo that is almost certainly the case… guess I’ll have to go figure that out. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it on my own - turns out that, with ANTLR and Maven, the `.g4` file must be inside a package of the same "name" as the rest of the project. For instance, my `.g4` file was inside `src/main/antlr4/mygrammar.g4`, when it should have been in `src/main/antlr4/com/myproject/mygrammar.g4` because the rest of the project's structure is `src/main/java/com/myproject/...`.

This, in turn, allows Maven to recognize the grammar location and generate the correct files with `mvn clean compile`.